# Java: Show label when cursor hovered in a button

Tags: java, button, netbeans-8

I'm currently working on a project in Java Netbeans but I don't know how to add label in a button when hovered. It will look like this:

[image]

So when I hovered my cursor on a button it will show a label. Sorry if I can't show any code because I don't have any idea on how to implement it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setToolTipText`

Example:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
button.setToolTipText("Click this button to make something happen.");
```

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)